# Ruby - Not able to read yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, file-handling

Hi all I am retriving data from database and storing it in a File.i am stroing data in yaml format.

```
  require 'mysql2'
  require 'yaml'
  client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost",:username => 'root' , :password => 'root' , :database => 'jgroup')
   results = client.query("SELECT * FROM jivegroup")
   File.open("D:/j.yml","w") do |file|
   results.each do |index|
   file.write(index.to_yaml);
   end
 end

   below is my file "j.yml"

    --- 
    groupID: 1000
    name: T1
    description: ""
    creationDate: 1209446456903
    modificationDate: 1378128624533
    --- 
    groupID: 1001
    name: T2
    description: 
    creationDate: 1209446473683
    modificationDate: 1378181717000
    ---
```

but whenver i am trying to load the above file with YAML::load it is giving my only first record. i want to load all records, plz help.
below is my code for reading yml file

```
    YAML::load( File.read('D:/jivegroup.yml') )
   {"groupID"=>1000, "name"=>"T1", "description"=>"", "creationDate"=>1209446456903, "modificationDate"=>1378128624533}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely want to go with this file design, then use `YAML::load_documents` to load more than one record at a time.

I would suggest instead using an list in the file. It seems cleaner to me (as what you have is a list of similar records, not a set of unrelated documents).

Answer (score 0):

Hey Finally found answer to my own question on stack overflow itself. i used YAML.load_stream(open("D:/jive_group.yml") instead  YAML::load( File.read('D:/jivegroup.yml') )